# Vue не подключается через Webpack4

Tags: vue.js, webpack4

В консоли ошибка: Vue is not defined

**Если подключить через CDN - все работает**

Хотя в выходном файле `main.66905f9e91666cf52fc4.js?da38ad338a15dcb4c609` код `vue.js` присутствует

Мои действия:

1. Скачиваем пакет npm i vue
2. Импортируем в index.js -> import 'vue'
3. В конфиге webpack -> точка входа index.js -> точка выхода -> dist/js/main.js
4. main.js успешно подключен внизу страницы
5. Проверяем main.js и находим там минифицированный vue.js
6. НО КОД С VUE НЕ РАБОТАЕТ

webpack.config.js

```
// Webpack v4
const path =                    require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin =    require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const FileManagerPlugin =       require('filemanager-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } =  require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin =       require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash =          require('webpack-md5-hash');

module.exports = {
  entry: { main: './src/js/index.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use:  [  'style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
            }
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'style.[contenthash].css'
    }),
    new FileManagerPlugin({
        onEnd: {
            copy: []
        }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: false,
        hash: true,
        template: './src/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new WebpackMd5Hash()
]
```

}

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
"autoprefixer": "^9.7.3",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
"css-loader": "^3.2.1",
"cssnano": "^4.1.10",
"file-loader": "^5.0.2",
"filemanager-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
"node-sass": "^4.13.0",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
"style-loader": "^1.0.1",
"vue-loader": "^15.7.2",
"webpack": "^4.41.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0",
"webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.6"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
  "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
  "jquery": "^3.4.1",
  "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
  "vue": "^2.6.10"
}
```

index.js

```
import 'vue';
```

index.html

```
    </footer>
<script src="js/main.66905f9e91666cf52fc4.js?da38ad338a15dcb4c609"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue!'
        },
        methods: {
            setMessage: function(event){
                this.message = event.target.value;
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: А настройки вебпака ?

Comment: нашел, в чем проблема

Comment: Нашли решение - поделитесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю пока, почему, но все дело было в подключении VUE в файле точки входа index.js

`import 'vue'` - так не работало

вот так работает:

```
 window.Vue = require('vue/dist/vue.js');
```

именно подключение к неминифицированному файлу библиотеки. Вероятно, это связано с загрузчиком и транпиляцией в ES2015

Comment: что-то у Вас совсем странное происходит. По сути, результат тот же, если бы Вы подключили Vue через тег script.

Comment: @Дмытрык в том-то и вопрос, что через тег script, если подключать, то работает без проблем, а через webpack только так:  window.Vue = require('vue/dist/vue.js');

Comment: Так vue в бандл попадает. В Вашем случае, зачем? Если можно стянуть его к себе в проект и подключить через html.

Comment: @Дмытрык а webpack тогда зачем? можно по старинке кучу скриптов подключать и городить огород. А как насчет актуальности версий пакетов? Тоже ручками?